# requestRouteToHost android

Tags: java, android, networking

Greetings everyone!
I'm getting rather fed up with android's ConnectivityManager class. I've been trying for 5 hours to get the requestRouteToHost to work. I'm running my code on the emulator but the requestRouteToHost always fails. I know I have connectivity because I called getActiveNetworkInfo() and it was connected. I've added the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE permissions to no avail. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT--------
The method InetAddress.isReachable fails as well. I was using the hostname java.sun.com as specified in the docs. I think this is a problem with the emulator.
Sam

Comment: Any chance of putting your code up so we can work out what could be going wrong. Steve

Comment: Well, sure. However, there isn't much to see. I mean what part would you like to see?

Comment: I'm not a noob or anything, I'm actually quite experienced with the android platform. This has just got me confused!

Comment: conn_man.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI, lookupHost("localhost")));

Answer (score 2):

Looks like requestRouteToHost() is not implemented for WiFi. WifiStateTracker private class does not have requestRouteToHost() implementation. Instead, default implementation from base class NetworkStateTracker always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend testing `requestRouteToHost()` with a real host. Not only am I unconvinced that `localhost` as a name is necessarily recognized on Android, it's going to be the device/emulator itself, which would go out via neither WiFi nor 3G, so I would expect `requestRouteToHost()` to fail.

You might also have a problem with wherever you are getting `lookupHost()` from. For example, I am not sure if [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295998/requestroutetohost-ip-argument) supports `localhost`.

Comment: I've tried a real host. I've tried google.com. Nothing works. Kind suggestion though

Comment: I have also read reports of bug in prior to ICS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322481/requestroutetohost-returns-false-on-wifi-interface If you know something please share it with the community?

Answer (score 0):

The requestRouteToHost(lookupHost()) combination you are doing is very risky

See your code:

```
conn_man.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI, lookupHost("localhost")))
```

Here, you first made a host lookup, and next you are requesting a route to it. It will work fine only for static addresses (like localhost), where no real lookup is done. If you need a DNS lookup to resolve host address, it will fail easily.
Generally, requestRouteToHost is handy for static addresses only.