# requestRouteToHost returns false on wifi interface

Tags: android, connectivity

public boolean requestRouteToHost (int networkType, int hostAddress)

This method in ConnectivityManager if used with networkType set to wifi interface always returns false.

[requestRouteToHost android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472016/requestroutetohost-android-) says it was never implemented for the wifi interface.

Even InetAddress.isReachable() always returns false for publicservers like google.com, java.com

Is there any specific reason why they fail? The only way I could test if there was connectivity was by executing the "ping" by using runtime exec().

Comment: Can you post a link to the bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug and this has been raised.

Comment: Can you post a link to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in ICS. My 2.3 Desire fails in the same way, but my 4.0.4 SGS2 gets a successful `true` result from requestRouteToHost over WiFi.