# requestRouteToHost always returns false

Tags: android, android-wifi

please check following code

```
 public boolean isOnline() {

ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 int networkType = ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI; 
return cm.requestRouteToHost(networkType, lookupHost("http://www.ati.ag"));
 //return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

}

  public static int lookupHost(String hostname) {
InetAddress inetAddress;
try {
    inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    return -1;
}
byte[] addrBytes;
int addr;
addrBytes = inetAddress.getAddress();
addr = ((addrBytes[3] & 0xff) << 24)
        | ((addrBytes[2] & 0xff) << 16)
        | ((addrBytes[1] & 0xff) << 8)
        |  (addrBytes[0] & 0xff);
System.out.println(addr);
return addr;
```

}

isOnline always returns false ,please help how does it work?
Or please tell me about any other way of checking server connectivity
Basic purpose is to check that , internet is available on local wifi or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a host name to `InetAddress.getByName`, not a URL, so this line:

```
return cm.requestRouteToHost(networkType, lookupHost("http://www.ati.ag"));
```

Should be:

```
return cm.requestRouteToHost(networkType, lookupHost("www.ati.ag"));
```

Probably this will work better.

Comment: Now I realize there is an old unanswered question about that. One possible explanation is that it is not implemented. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2680765/972850

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to your approach, if your purpose is only to check if Wifi is available you can try this. This worked for me:

```
ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(cm==null)
    return false;
NetworkInfo networkInfo=cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if(networkInfo==null)
    return false;
return networkInfo.isConnected();
```

Comment: The question is talking about Internet on Wifi, have a look at the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/android-detect-if-device-has-internet-connection